# Limit of $\frac{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}{4x+\pi}$ as x goes to $-\pi/4$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to -\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}{4x+\pi}$$

Comment: I can't even read it, let alone fine[sic] the limit.  It looks like you can just plug in $-\frac \pi 4$ for $x$ or are there some parentheses missing?

Comment: Do you mean $$\lim_{x\to -\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\cos x + \sin x}{4x+\pi}\ ?$$

Comment: limit of (cos(x)+sin(x))/(4x+π)  
x to −π/4

Comment: yes this what  mean

Comment: Your denominator is not going to be zero, actually is there is no problem. It is just a point on the graph

Comment: @imranfat $$4\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+\pi=-\pi+\pi=0$$

Comment: yes i know that imranfat thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The denominator is $$4\left(x + \frac{π}{4}\right)$$

The numerator is $$\sqrt2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\sin x + \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cos x\right)$$

Which becomes: $$\sqrt2\sin\left(x + \frac{π}{4}\right)$$

Let  $t = x + \dfrac{π}{4}$

As $x → -\dfrac{π}{4}, t → 0$

Hence, the limit is: $$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sqrt2\sin t}{4t} = \frac{\sqrt2}{4}$$